# How to extract components from an object of class "spec"?

Tags: r

I am trying to construct a table of power spectra and run into this problem:

Define the table:

```
V <- tibble(month=double(),day=double(),hour=double(),minutes=double(),
               frequency=double(),power=double(),period=double())
```

compute the spectrum:

```
 S <- spec.pgram(Spec2d$Inst,spans=windowSize,log="yes")
```

which creates an object of class "spec"

I need to extract the data from S and put it into V. When I try:

```
 V$frequency <- S$freq
```

I get this error message:

```
Error: Assigned data `S$freq` must be compatible with existing data.
x Existing data has 0 rows.
x Assigned data has 48 rows.
ℹ Only vectors of size 1 are recycled.
```

which doesn't make sense to me. I have tried to coerce `S$freq` into different different types of objects but nothing works.

`S$freq` is a vector of length 48 as in the error message

What is going on? Is there a workaround?

Comment: I am getting a few errors running the code: 1) `could not find function tibble` 2) `object 'Spec2d' not found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't initialise the dataframe/tibble first. Try :

```
S <- spec.pgram(Spec2d$Inst,spans=windowSize,log="yes")
V <- data.frame(frequency = S$freq)
```

Comment: Thank you! That solves my problem. I wish that the error message had been clearer